# Convert multiple SQL code with multiple subqueries into a single query

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, left-join, inner-join

I'm starting to handle an old database that was generated years ago with ACCESS. All the queries have been designed with the ACCESS query wizard and they seem to be very time consuming and I would like to improve their performance.

All queries depend on at least three subqueries and I would like to rewrite the SQL code to convert them into a single query.

Here you have an example of what I'm talking about:

This is the main query:

> SELECT Subquery1.pid, Table4.SIB, Subquery1.event,
> Subquery1.event_date, Subquery2.GGG, Subquery3.status FROM Subquery1
> LEFT JOIN ((Table4  LEFT JOIN Subquery2  ON Table4.SIB =
> Subquery2.SIB)  LEFT JOIN Subquery3  ON Table4.SIB = Subquery3.SIB)
> ON Subquery1.pid = Table4.PID;

This main query depends on three subqueries:

Subquery1

> SELECT Table2.id, Table2.pid, Table2.npid, Table3.event_date,
> Table3.event, Table3.notes, Table2.other FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table3
> ON Table2.id = Table3.subject_id WHERE (((Table2.pid) Is Not Null) AND
> ((Table3.event_date)>#XX/XX/XXXX#) AND ((Table3.event) Like "*AAAA" Or
> (Table3.event)="BBBB")) ORDER BY Table2.pid, Table3.event_date DESC;

Subquery2

> SELECT Table1.SIB, IIf(Table1.GGG Like "AAA","BBB", IIf(Table1.GGG
> Like "CCC","BBB", IIf(Table1.GGG Like "DDD","DDD","EEE"))) AS GGG FROM
> Table1;

Subquery3

> SELECT Table5.SIB, Table5.PID, IIf(Table5.field1 Like
> "1","ZZZ",IIf(Table5.field1 Like "2","ZZZ",IIf(Table5.field1 Like
> "3","ZZZ",IIf(Table5.field1 Like "4","HHH",IIf(Table5.field1 Like
> "5","HHH",IIf(Table5.field1 Like "6","HHH","UUU")))))) AS SSS FROM
> Table5;

Which would be the best way of improving the performance of this query and converting all the subqueries into a single statement?

I can handle each subquery, but I'm having a hard time joining them together.

Comment: As far as merging them into one is concerned you should be able to simply replace the references in the main query's FROM with the actual subqueries aliased as their name; for example `FROM Subquery1 ....` becomes `FROM (SELECT Table2.id ..... Table3.event_date DESC) AS Subquery1 ....` _Obviously, you'll need to translate all queries to the appropriate sql dialect as well; MySQL won't like `IIf` or `#date#`._

Comment: That is the way I was trying to do it, but it always returns me errors

Comment: Did you translate the queries used for the subqueries and make sure they run correctly on their own before trying to merge?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I was missing one of the AS Subqueries statements. Now it works!! The next question would be: does it make any sense running the subqueries as Temporary tables or would the performance be exactly the same?

Comment: Using temp tables is really dependent on too many factors to be able to give a definitive answer; however, there is a strong argument against even having the latter two subqueries as subqueries. It looks likely you can just join Table1 and Table5 directly to Table4, and move their subquery versions' SELECT field calculations into the main query's SELECT.

Comment: Actually, it is likely you can start with Subquery1; insert `LEFT JOIN`s for Table4, Table1, and Table5 to it before it's `WHERE`, and then just adjust it's SELECT to reflect the original query's final select fields.

Comment: To be honest with you I'm not an SQL expert. I've got the basic knowledge and I understand what you say, but it is hard for me to make these left joins. Can you write the example for the first left join? Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127749/discussion-between-yatrosin-and-uueerdo).

Answer (score 1):

If this:

`Table5.field1 Like "3"`

is really how some of your subqueries are written (without actual wild characters) you can save a lot of time by changing it to

`Table5.field1="3"`

Comment: How is this an answer to OP? Better as a comment.

Comment: Joining the sub-queries into a single query will not result in any gains in performance. Fixing each sub-query to work faster will.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''you can create transient tables for each sub query'''
CREATE Transient table1 AS
        '''Your sub query goes here'''
CREATE Transient table2 AS
        '''Your sub query goes here'''
'''Main query to merge them into one'''
SELECT '''column names'''
FROM 
table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_column = table2.common_column
LEFT JOIN table3
ON table1.common_column = table3.common_column
'''similarly you can combine all sub queries/transient tables'''
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).